# Programming language for Zigbee

Tags: c, zigbee, java, python

I have done a small research in the field of zigbee. But , a small conflict b/w using python or java or c for zigbee coding in case of remote monitoring .

Comment: It depends on: with which language YOU are comfortable!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you really understand what you are talking about here.

"Zigbee", or IEEE 802.15.4, is a *protocol*. As such, it has no "programming language".

Theoretically, it's completely possible to implement a system which can handle the zigbee protocol in any programming language, assuming that whatever language you're using has adequate hardware support to interface with whatever tranciever you are using.

Realistically, in probably ~98% of the situations where you're building a IEEE 802.15.4 compatible system, you're going to be working with a small, embedded microprocessor. *The fact that you're working on a small MCU, not the fact that the system needs to talk IEEE 802.15.4* is what is responsible for the fact that most IEEE 802.15.4 systems are programmed in C, as higher level languages (such as java or python) are ill-suited for running on small micros.

Comment: yeah , i agree . but to build applications such as ..... 1. remote patient monitoring, 2.industrial automation etc needs some kind of coding stuff , web servers .

Comment: @hanumesh - Ok, wow, you need to do a lot more reading, and then come back and re-ask your question.

Comment: Zigbee is not protocol, is is a protocol stack.

Answer (score 1):

For industrial applications on small MCUs, Ada could be on the list of candidates, especially where high reliability is necessary, as in medical applications.

It's a compiled language like C, and has very good facilities for manipulating bits on ports, but it isn't available for every MPU. Arm, AVR and (experimentally) MSP430 processors can be targetted so far.

As Ian's comment suggests, Ada is often written off without any regard to its actual capabilities, due to possibly obsolete opinions about limitations such as program size.

Addressing the specific point, my smallest Ada executable on AVR is 65 bytes. Independent control of two stepper motors on the AdaFruit Motorshield came in about 600 bytes and up. A basic digital watch including display scanning and osc fault detection on MSP430, under a kilobyte of program memory; in all cases, only a few bytes of RAM required. On the other hand if you need full tasking, that does require more!

EDIT: What compiler do I use? 
Basically gcc 4.72 built with --enable-languages=ada,c,c++ (aka Gnat).

For AVR, the [AVR-Ada project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/avr-ada/) provides the necessary patches and script to build the compiler, plus minimal RTS, and device support. The front page only highlights an old (1.1) version, I recommend a dig around to get the newer [1.2.1 version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/avr-ada/files/avr-ada/Source%20Dist/) with basic threading support.

There is also commercial support for the AVR from Adacore, as well as a [GPL version](http://libre.adacore.com/download/configurations) I haven't tried (select AVR-elf-windows as the platform)

For MSP430, the [tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msp430ada/) are at a much more primitive stage, the project hasn't been around long and only tested on Linux. (I confess it's only my project so far) with - at the moment - no support for threading or >64k memory.

For ARM, I can't suggest a specific toolchain but there are several including [Dragonlace](http://www.dragonlace.net/) which covers Android.

Comment: "For industrial applications on small MCUs, Ada could be on the list of candidates" - Only for large values of "small".  I must say that I have not tried but, from my experience of working in Ada, I think that it is only a realistic proposition for the larger MSPs.  Those below 1K RAM might find it rather difficult.

Comment: My smallest Ada executable on AVR is 65 bytes. On the other hand if you need full tasking, that does require more...

Comment: @Brian What compiler do you use?

Comment: I have never met anyone programming embedded systems using Ada. I personally just don't think it's such a marketable skill.

Comment: I wrote Ada for embedded systems back in the late 1980s.  I have been using C for the last nearly 20 years.  Most of the problems that have caused the real hard to find errors just wouldn't have been possible in Ada.

Comment: @Ian : Bingo! If I'm being paid to write C, I will. But I can't afford to waste my precious hobby time on it! Plus, Ada now (95, 2005 and now 2012) is a much more usable language than it was back then.

Answer (score 0):

Well as Connor Wolf mentions, it's a protocol so you can write programs that communicate via that protocol in every language you want. 
I've done development where I wrote firmware for MCUs in C and tested them from my laptop with a USB->tranceiver dongle. I normally write the software to communicate with the USB dongle in Python.

Usually you just manipulate a string (or a data structure that gets serialized to a string) and you send that off.